# Complex vector space on R

Tags: vector-spaces

Is it possible to define a complex vector space structure on the real numbers?

If we assume that it is possible and let $\alpha = i \cdot 1$, I've been able to show that the following must be true:

1) $i \cdot \alpha = -1$,

2) $\alpha$ is irrational,

3) $(a+bi) \cdot (c+d\alpha) = (ac-bd) + (ad+bc)\alpha$ for every $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q}$.

The subgroup $H = \{a+b\alpha: a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ can be turned into an $\mathbb{Q}(i)$-vector space using equation (3), taking $\alpha$ as any irrational number.

This is all I've got. Any hints to a full solution of this question? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by a complex vector space structure? If I take any bijection $\mathbb R \cong \mathbb C$ and "pullback" the complex vector space structure on $\mathbb C$ to $\mathbb R$, would that satisfy your definition?

Comment: No, becuase I want to use the usual abelian group structure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Can you state in the question what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: I've found the answer. The answer lies in the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are isomorphic as abelian groups because they are both $\mathbb{Q}$-vector sapces of the same dimension. Then we can transfer the structure of $\mathbb{C}$-vector space of $\mathbb{C}$ onto $\mathbb{R}$ via this isomorphism. Of couse, we assume here the Axiom of Choice.